# SQL Server: How to show my data a specific order

Tags: t-sql

I like to show my data a specific way. i tried one way but no luck. Here i am giving sample data for two table which help other to reproduce the output.

Here is my sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCSMModels](
    [Ticker] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [DisplayText] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Type] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 1, 0, N'Key Drugs', N'GROUP     ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 2, 1, N'R&D', N'LINEITEM  ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 3, 1, N'Net Revenue', N'LINEITEM  ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 4, 0, N'Key Fin', N'GROUP     ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 5, 4, N'Diluted', N'LINEITEM  ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 6, 2, N'% Total Revenue', N'BM        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 7, 2, N'% Change (YoY)', N'BM        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 8, 2, N'% Change (QoQ)', N'BM        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 9, 3, N'% Total Revenue', N'BM        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 10, 3, N'% Change (YoY)', N'BM        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 11, 3, N'% Change (QoQ)', N'BM        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 12, 5, N'% Gaap', N'BM        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 13, 5, N'% Change (YoY)', N'BM        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) VALUES (N'ANAB', 14, 5, N'% Change (QoQ)', N'BM        ')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] OFF
GO


INSERT INTO tblOutputDetl (Ticker,EarningsID, Section, LineItem, Broker, Period, ItemValue)
VALUES 
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2010 FYA',10),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2011 FYA',56),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2012 FYA',11),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2010 FYA',99),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2011 FYA',26),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2012 FYA',87),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2010 FYA',12),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2011 FYA',21),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2012 FYA',71),
       
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','BC','2010 FYA',12),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','BC','2011 FYA',79),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','BC','2012 FYA',55),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','AK','2010 FYA',20),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','AK','2011 FYA',12),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','AK','2012 FYA',17),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2010 FYA',21),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2011 FYA',22),
    ('ANAB',1,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2012 FYA',27),
       
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2010 FYA',10),
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2011 FYA',56),
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2012 FYA',11),
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2010 FYA',99),
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2011 FYA',26),
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2012 FYA',87),
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2010 FYA',12),
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2011 FYA',21),
    ('ANAB',1,'Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2012 FYA',71),

    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2010 FYA',19),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2011 FYA',51),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2012 FYA',17),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2010 FYA',90),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2011 FYA',22),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2012 FYA',81),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2010 FYA',11),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2011 FYA',23),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2012 FYA',79),
       
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','BC','2010 FYA',07),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','BC','2011 FYA',77),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','BC','2012 FYA',56),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','AK','2010 FYA',29),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','AK','2011 FYA',13),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','AK','2012 FYA',18),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2010 FYA',25),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2011 FYA',23),
    ('ANAB',2,'Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2012 FYA',28),
       
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2010 FYA',11),
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2011 FYA',55),
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2012 FYA',13),
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2010 FYA',98),
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2011 FYA',27),
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2012 FYA',81),
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2010 FYA',11),
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2011 FYA',26),
    ('ANAB',2,'Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2012 FYA',76)
```

Parent Child data relation stored in table **tblCSMModels** relation establish with **ID and ParentID**.

This is my sample desired output

```
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+--------+------------------+-----------+--+
|     Section     | Line Item  |   DisplayText   | Broker |    BM_Element    |   Type    |  |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+--------+------------------+-----------+--+
| NULL            | NULL       | Key Drugs       | NULL   | NULL             | GROUP     |  |
| Consensus Model | R&D        | R&D             | AK     | NULL             | BROKER    |  |
| Consensus Model | R&D        | R&D             | BC     | NULL             | BROKER    |  |
| Consensus Model | R&D        | R&D             | NH     | NULL             | BROKER    |  |
| Consensus Model | R&D        | R&D             | NULL   | NULL             | Consensus |  |
| Consensus Model | R&D        | % Total Revenue | NULL   | % Total Revenue  | BM        |  |
| Consensus Model | R&D        | % Change (YoY)  | NULL   | % Change (YoY)   | BM        |  |
| Consensus Model | R&D        | % Change (QoQ)  | NULL   | % Change (QoQ)   | BM        |  |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+--------+------------------+-----------+--+
```

Table tblCSMModels has relational data where Group would be parent and a Group can have a child group.
Line Item will be always under a group and BM element will be always child of a group.

In the desired output i just give data for one line item called **R&D** which is child of **Key Drugs Group**. R&D lineitem has some BM elements.

In this fashion i have to show each line item with their Groups,Broker,BM elements etc.

Hierarchy of data is like ->

1. First i need to show a line item which has a group and that group may have another parent group. Group Nesting is not limited. a group can have another group and again another group can have another group and this nesting is Nth.

So i have to show all parent groups for each line item. after printing group names then Broker code will come. Broker code is in tblOutputDetl table and relation will be based on line item name. so for each line item all distinct broker will be shown.

after showing all broker then that specific line item will be shown.

after showing line item i have to show all BM elements for that line item. this relation is in tblCSMModels table. in tblCSMModels table each line item has few BM element which i need to show.

### I tried this but no luck

```
;WITH DirectReports as 
 (
     SELECT      
                 ID, 
                 ParentID, 
                 Displaytext, 
                 Type,
                 hierarchy = FORMAT(ID,'0000'), 
                 level = 0
    
     FROM        tblCSMModels 
     WHERE       ISNULL(ParentID, 0) = 0
    
     UNION ALL
     SELECT      
                 e.ID, 
                 e.ParentID, 
                 e.Displaytext, 
                 e.Type,
                 hierarchy = d.hierarchy + '.' + FORMAT(e.id,'0000'), 
                 level = level + 1
    
     FROM        tblCSMModels e
     JOIN        DirectReports d on e.ParentID = d.ID
 )

 --select * from DirectReports order by hierarchy
SELECT ZZ.Section,ZZ.LineItem,ZZ.DisplayText,ZZ.Broker,ZZ.BM_Element,ZZ.Type FROM
(
    Select AA.Section,AA.LineItem,CSM.DisplayText,'' Broker,'' BM_Element,'GROUP' Type
    FROM tblCSMModels CSM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (
        select Section,Lineitem,'' Broker,'' BM_Element from tblOutputDetl WHERE Ticker='ANAB'
    ) AA ON AA.LineItem=CSM.DisplayText WHERE CSM.Type='GROUP'

    UNION ALL

    Select AA.Section,AA.LineItem,CSM.DisplayText,AA.Broker,'' BM_Element,'BROKER' Type
    FROM tblCSMModels CSM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (
        select Section,Lineitem,Broker from tblOutputDetl WHERE Ticker='ANAB'
        GROUP BY Section,Lineitem,Broker

    ) AA ON AA.LineItem=CSM.DisplayText WHERE CSM.Type='LINEITEM'

    UNION ALL

    Select AA.Section,AA.LineItem,CSM.DisplayText,'' Broker,'' BM_Element,'Consensus' Type
    FROM tblCSMModels CSM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (
        select TOP 1 Section,Lineitem from tblOutputDetl WHERE Ticker='ANAB'
        GROUP BY Section,Lineitem
    ) AA ON AA.LineItem=CSM.DisplayText WHERE CSM.Type='LINEITEM'

    UNION ALL

    Select d.Section,d.LineItem,MAX(AA.DisplayText) DisplayText,'' Broker,MAX(AA.DisplayText) AS BM_Element,'BM' Type
    FROM tblOutputDetl d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (
            SELECT e.DisplayText,m.DisplayText AS LineItem
            FROM tblCSMModels e INNER JOIN tblCSMModels m ON e.ParentID=m.ID
            WHERE e.Type='BM'
    ) AA ON AA.LineItem=d.LineItem /*WHERE CSM.Type='BM'*/
    GROUP BY d.Section,d.LineItem

) ZZ LEFT JOIN DirectReports m ON ZZ.DisplayText=m.DisplayText
ORDER BY m.hierarchy
```

### Order would be this way

When Final output will appear then this way data should be order which maintain parent child relation.

```
;WITH DirectReports as 
 (
     SELECT      
                 ID, 
                 ParentID, 
                 Displaytext, 
                 Type,
                 hierarchy = FORMAT(ID,'0000'), 
                 level = 0
    
     FROM        tblCSMModels 
     WHERE       ISNULL(ParentID, 0) = 0
    
     UNION ALL
     SELECT      
                 e.ID, 
                 e.ParentID, 
                 e.Displaytext, 
                 e.Type,
                 hierarchy = d.hierarchy + '.' + FORMAT(e.id,'0000'), 
                 level = level + 1
    
     FROM        tblCSMModels e
     JOIN        DirectReports d on e.ParentID = d.ID
 )

 select * from DirectReports order by hierarchy
```

Here is [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50fb5/2)

Comment: Your SQL Has no `ORDER BY` Without an ORDER BY there is no guaranteed order.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid see this area 'Order would be this way' where i mention how data should be ordered.

Comment: Are you authorized to disclose the DDL for `tblOutputDetl`? Better yet, create a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that demonstrates the issue. A semicolon is a _statement terminator_, not a prefix. Tip: Don't introduce _magic values_ when they aren't needed. Is `ISNULL(ParentID, 0) = 0` really what you mean or is it a bad way to write `ParentId is NULL` while handling the value `0` incorrectly?

Comment: here is sql fiddle where all data exist. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50fb5/2   if you see the output then can see R&D line item has 3 BM item but showing only 2. output is not right one. first lineitem wise all distinct broker should show, then one lineitem related row should come which will be consider as consensus and next line item wise all BM item should show. in this fashion each line item data will come with parent child hierarchy wise.

Comment: Well, that's an improvement. Are table aliases expensive for you? Recycling the same (meaningless) one over and over (`AA`) in a single query doesn't make it easier to follow. At least the oft-used `CSM` has a bit of meaning.

Comment: @HABO Sir/Madam if you understand what kind of output i am trying to achieve then please compose a sample sql because i failed to do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now proper output is coming. i made some changes in sql. here is working code.

```
 ;WITH DirectReports as 
   (
       SELECT      
                   ID, 
                   ParentID, 
                   Displaytext, 
                   Type,
                   hierarchy = FORMAT(ID,'0000'), 
                   level = 0
            
       FROM        tblCSMModels 
       WHERE       ISNULL(ParentID, 0) = 0
            
       UNION ALL
       SELECT      
                   e.ID, 
                   e.ParentID, 
                   e.Displaytext, 
                   e.Type,
                   hierarchy = d.hierarchy + '.' + FORMAT(e.id,'0000'), 
                   level = level + 1
            
       FROM        tblCSMModels e
       JOIN        DirectReports d on e.ParentID = d.ID
   )
        
   --select * from DirectReports order by hierarchy
   SELECT  ZZ.Section,ZZ.LineItem,ZZ.DisplayText,ZZ.Broker,ZZ.BM_Element,ZZ.Type FROM
  (
   Select AA.Section,AA.LineItem,CSM.DisplayText,'' Broker,'' BM_Element,'GROUP' Type,csm.id,csm.ParentID,0 AS RowOrder
   FROM tblCSMModels CSM
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  
   (
   select Section,Lineitem,'' Broker,'' BM_Element from tblOutputDetl WHERE Ticker='ANAB'
   ) AA ON AA.LineItem=CSM.DisplayText WHERE CSM.Type='GROUP'
        
   UNION 
        
   Select AA.Section,AA.LineItem,CSM.DisplayText,AA.Broker,'' BM_Element,'BROKER' Type,csm.id,csm.ParentID,1 AS RowOrder
   FROM tblCSMModels CSM
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  
   (
   select Section,Lineitem,Broker from tblOutputDetl WHERE Ticker='ANAB'
   GROUP BY Section,Lineitem,Broker
        
   ) AA ON AA.LineItem=CSM.DisplayText WHERE CSM.Type='LINEITEM'
        
   UNION 
        
   Select AA.Section,AA.LineItem,CSM.DisplayText,'' Broker,'' BM_Element,'Consensus' Type,csm.id,csm.ParentID,2 AS RowOrder
   FROM tblCSMModels CSM
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  
   (
   select TOP 1 Section,Lineitem from tblOutputDetl WHERE Ticker='ANAB'
   GROUP BY Section,Lineitem
   ) AA ON AA.LineItem=CSM.DisplayText WHERE CSM.Type='LINEITEM'
        
   UNION 
        
   Select d.Section,d.LineItem,AA.DisplayText,'' Broker,AA.DisplayText AS BM_Element,'BM' Type,id,ParentID,3 AS RowOrder
   FROM tblOutputDetl d
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  
   (
   SELECT e.DisplayText,m.DisplayText AS LineItem,e.id,e.ParentID
   FROM tblCSMModels e INNER JOIN tblCSMModels m ON e.ParentID=m.ID
   WHERE e.Type='BM'
   ) AA ON AA.LineItem=d.LineItem   
  ) ZZ 
  LEFT JOIN DirectReports m ON ZZ.DisplayText=m.DisplayText and zz.ID=m.id and zz.ParentID=m.ParentID
  ORDER BY m.hierarchy,RowOrder
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50fb5/5)